# $C^k$ version of Hadamard's Lemma. Differentiability of the remainder

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, real-analysis

Let $f:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ be of $C^k$ class, let $0\in\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ and let $\Omega$ be star shaped at $0.$

From [Hadamard's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard%27s_lemma) we know that we can write function $f$ as

$$f(x)=f(0)+\sum_{i=1}^n \overbrace{x_i\int_0^1\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(tx)dt}^{R_i(x)}.$$

This is in fact [multivariate case of Taylor's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Taylor.27s_theorem_for_multivariate_functions) with the remainder of first order.

**Question.** Is $R_i$ of $C^k$ class for $i=1,\dots,n$?

For $n=1$ the answer is yes, cause then $R(x)=f(x)-f(0).$ Problem is with $n>1.$

---

**Remarks.**
Few days ago I posted [similar question on Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2286305/differentiability-of-the-remainder-in-taylors-theorem-1d-vs-2d), but it didn't draw much attention.

After reading Whitney's article I thought that the the answer may be nontrivial so this is why I post here as well.

I just can add that from Whitney's paper we immediately know that

$$ x\int_0^1\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(tx,y)dt$$

is of $C^k$ class, but in our case we have

$$ x\int_0^1\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(tx,ty)dt.$$

I can't find a way to transform Whitney's argument to my case.

*Whitney, Hassler*, [**Differentiability of the remainder term in Taylor's formula**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1215/S0012-7094-43-01014-2), Duke Math. J. 10, 153-158 (1943). [ZBL0063.08234](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0063.08234).

Comment: Related, but not quite the same https://mathoverflow.net/q/250949/3948

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, not in general. Consider $f(x,y)=(x+y)|x+y|$. This is $C^1$ with partial derivatives $f_x=f_y=2|x+y|$, but you lose one derivative when you form
$$
R= x \int_0^1 2|tx+ty|\, dt = x|x+y| .
$$

Comment: So my intuintion was wrong. Thank you and I encourage you to post the same answer in my Math.SE question to collect the bounty.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2286305/differentiability-of-the-remainder-in-taylors-theorem-1d-vs-2d